# Managing compass calibration alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location, cllocationmanager

As per Apple documentation:

```
- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager
```

> If you return YES from this method, Core Location displays the heading
>   calibration alert on top of the current window immediately.
>
> If you return NO from this method or do not provide an implementation for it
>   in your delegate, Core Location does not display the heading
>   calibration alert. Even if the alert is not displayed, calibration can
>   still occur naturally when any interfering magnetic fields move away
>   from the device.

I want the exact behaviour as Apple documented that **if return NO or do not provide an implementation alert will not be shown**.

I'm getting exactly opposite behaviour. I tried the following:

1. I didn't provide the method implementation mentioned above.
   ***Result : Still getting the calibration alert***
2. I provided the method implementation and return YES/NO tried both. 
   ***Result : Still getting the calibration alert, seems like there is no affect of an implementation.***

**NOTE: Method implementation was being called, when implemented the method.**

I did a lot of research as well, found some similar question too on stackoverflow but didn't got the solution from any of them.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Adding a source:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  self.locationManager.delegate = self;
  self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
  self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0;

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0

  if (IS_IOS8_AND_UP) 
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
#endif
  [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];


- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:
            (CLLocationManager *)manager {
  return NO;
}
```

This method is being called before showing the calibrating window.

Comment: Is the method being called at all?

Comment: I put together a quick sample and it seems to be working as expected.  Could you include your code setting up the `CLLocationManager`?

Comment: @David : Added the source code and method is being called every time before showing calibrate window.

Comment: Using almost exactly the same code (`requestAlwaysAuthorization` isn't conditionalized), things work exactly as expected/documented.

Comment: @David: you mean to say to remove this condition "if (IS_IOS8_AND_UP) " from "requestAlwaysAuthorization"?

Comment: Yeah, but that shouldn't really matter.  The 'correct' to handle it btw, is `if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {... }`  Always check for the feature, not the OS.

Comment: @David : Yeah, but still i'm getting calibrate screen. I'm not able to figure out what causes it.

Comment: Not sure either. Using essentially identical code everything worked exact,y as,expected.  Just to make sure, you've got the Info.plist string for always authoriAtion, right?

Comment: Do you have a complete failing example?